# MySQL random with gaps of 40+ million rows

Tags: mysql, random, solr

I've held back asking since I feel this question is asked so much, but still lacking a definitive answer:

*Objects* table: 40M+ rows filled with UPC, EIN, ISBN as obj_id primary key. Gaps

*Obj_Cat* table: Linking Objects to Categories. Columns of | obj_id | cat_id |

**Question:** What is the best way to return 5 non-sequential random obj_id? Is there a better way than what I listed?

**Solution1:** `SELECT objects.obj_id FROM objects left join obj_cat on objects.obj_id=obj_cat.obj_id WHERE obj_cat.cat_id=cat_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;` Run 5 times

- Very slow with large tables.

**Solution2:** `SELECT obj_id FROM objects WHERE obj_id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(obj_id) * RAND()) FROM`objects`) LIMIT 1;` Run 5 times (did not include obj_cat join to keep it more easily understood)

- Best solution if your rows are gapless or have negligible gaps. Very fast.
- Does not work well with categories, as there will inevitably be gaps in the numbering.

**Solution3:** `SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(objects.*)) AS`offset`FROM objects, obj_cat WHERE objects.obj_id=obj_cat.obj_id AND obj_cat.cat_id=cat_id; SELECT obj_id FROM objects LIMIT $offset, 1` Run 5 times

- Very flexible. Much faster than solution 1. Works with gaps. But at 40M+ rows, a single 'LIMIT $offset, 1' can still take 1 min.

I used Solution 3, but it is slow. My current solution is move use Solr randomsortfield, since it is easy to specify my category in the fq.

**Solr Solution:** `?q=*&fl=obj_id&fq=cat:(cat_id)&sort=random_* desc&rows=5`

- Pretty fast, takes about 45 sec per category but returns 5 non-sequential results in on go.

Is there a better way that people have discovered when dealing with large data sets? I know this seems like a duplicate question, but figured I'd contribute my experiences with a 40M+ table.

Answer (score 0):

With a dataset this large you can't do on-the-fly calculations like this.  You need to take advantage of the time-memory tradeoff.  Create a new unsigned integer index column in your obj_cat table with a width greater than your maximum number of rows and populate each row with a random number.  This way you can simply generate a random number and directly select the closest match five times.  This will be several orders of magnitude faster than trying to use an ORDER BY RAND().

Comment: I understand that concept, but that won't work if I want to select random values withing a particular category, unless I have a table for each category with random int. And given over 2000 categories I don't like the idea of over 2000 tables. Plus a given object can have multiple categories.

Comment: @AnthonyLin - Can you keep the category_id in the table with the table of random ints?